# preg_match time and allow but ignore rest

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im trying to match 24H time in pregmatch and alow spaces and date to be appended on the back.
Im only interested in the time which is the first 5 chars.

so time (first 5 chars) and any thing after that should be allowed, but ignored.

**example**
`23:20 2014-09-29`

How far off am I?

```
     $time = '10:30';
     $pattern = '~^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$~i';
     if (preg_match($pattern, $time, $m)) {
         print_r(" THATS IS A WRAP");
     } else {
         print_r(" INVALID TIME ");
     }
```

example
`23:20 2014-09-29`

Comment: Can you give some example of accepted and wrong sentences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `$` anchor:

```
$time = '10:30';
$pattern = '~^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])~';
//                                     here __^
if (preg_match($pattern, $time, $m)) {
     print_r(" THATS IS A WRAP");
} else {
     print_r(" INVALID TIME ");
}
```

Also, the `/i` modifier is superfluous here because there are not any letters.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you suggest any good regex tutorial sites?

Comment: @mornenel: You're welcome. Here is a good site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

```
^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

Try this.You were not far.Just that you were not matching `am` or `pm` .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/5

Comment: oh man, thanks but sorry. it was ment to be `23:20` or similar.

Comment: But what about if there is a time after that. It does not find it.